How to build google cloud functions for Active Collab integration?
I'm trying to extract our Active Collab data to Google BigQuery using a Google Cloud Function and Fivetran, but I encounter errors.
Is there somebody out there who have done data integration between Active Collab and Google Cloud Functions and would be happy to share with me the code I need to implement?
Thanks.
Things I tried:

using webhooks - but with this option I loose the historical data which is really problematic
I was trying to implement interaction with Active Collab API using the github repo with the feather SDK they provided, but I am not familiar with coding language so I get errors as well.

